# How to set focus to TextField inside ListView delegate?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have ListView with some text input fields inside it:

```
Window {
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: textModel
        ListElement {
            text: "Bill Smith"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "John Brown"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Sam Wise"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        width: 180; height: 200
        focus: true

        model: textModel
        delegate: RowLayout{
            id: layout
            Label {
                text: model.text
            }
            TextField {
                text: model.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to set input focus to the first TextField in the list. How can I do this? If I add `focus: true` in ListView it does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to activate the focus of the TextField using the [`ListView.isCurrentItem`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-listview.html#isCurrentItem-attached-prop) property:

```
ListView {
    id: view
    width: 180; height: 200
    focus: true
    model: textModel
    delegate: RowLayout{
        id: layout
        Label {
            text: model.text
        }
        TextField {
            focus: layout.ListView.isCurrentItem
            text: model.text
        }
    }
    // Component.onCompleted: view.currentIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. I try other solution: focus: model.index == 0 and it does not work. I do not understand why.